How to implement O(1) position-lookups on an ordered set of unique IDs?
I think my situation is not uncommon, but I've been having trouble coming up with a way to make my code efficient with large data sets.
My data set is a list of unique IDs (32-bit unsigned integers, if that matters) in which the ordering of the list is significant (i.e. the calling code expects the IDs to be kept in the order they were inserted).
The calling code is allowed to insert new (unique) IDs into the list at any position and/or remove IDs from the list.  The list can grow quite large (e.g. tens of thousands of IDs long)
Because the list is used to populate a QTableView, I need fast (ideally O(1)) lookups between a given unique-ID and its current position in the list, and vice-versa.
My current code stores the list as a std::vector<uint32_t>, so that looking up the ID at the nth position is just a matter of indexing into the vector.  (See int32_t getIDAtRow(size_t rowIdx) const in the example code below)
For the reverse-lookup, my code generates a std::unordered_map<uint32_t, size_t> so that given a unique ID as a key, it can quickly return the row-index where that unique ID is currently located.  (See ssize_t getRowIndexForID(uint32_t id) const in the example code below).
This all works fairly well if the data is static; however, if the calling code starts doing a lot insertions or deletions near the beginning of list, each insertion/deletion invalidates most of the items in the reverse-lookup table, so they then have to be regenerated, which can get very slow.  I've tried various strategies to mitigate the performance issue (such as delaying the regeneration or doing only a partial regeneration), but none of them are entirely satisfactory -- I can still always find some calling pattern that results in slow performance due to excessive regeneration.
So my question is:  is there some other data-structure I can use here to get better performance for my bi-directional ID<->RowIndex lookups, that can remain efficient even when the IDs list is large and being inserted-into and/or removed-from a lot?  i.e. is there something that wouldn't require an O(N) reverse-table-regeneration after an insert or delete?
Compilable toy example code is below, in case it helps explain the problem better.
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

class IDToRowMap
{  
public:
   IDToRowMap() {/* empty */}

   // append a new unique ID to the end of our ordered IDs list
   void appendID(uint32_t id) 
   {
      if (getRowIndexForID(id) >= 0) 
      {
         printf("Error, ID %u is already in the table!\n", id);
      }
      else
      {
         idsInRowOrder.push_back(id);
         idToRowIndex[id] = idsInRowOrder.size()-1;
      }
   }
   
   // insert a new unique ID into the middle of our ordered IDs list
   void insertIDAtRow(uint32_t id, size_t rowIdx)
   {
      if (getRowIndexForID(id) >= 0) 
      {
         printf("Error, ID %u is already in the table!\n", id);
      }
      else if (rowIdx < idsInRowOrder.size())
      {
         idsInRowOrder.insert(idsInRowOrder.begin()+rowIdx, id);
         regenerate_reverse_index_starting_at(rowIdx);
      }
      else 
      {
         appendID(id);
      }  
   }        
            
   // remove the specified ID from our list
   void removeID(uint32_t id)
   {           
      const ssize_t rowIdx = getRowIndexForID(id);
      if (rowIdx >= 0)
      {
         idsInRowOrder.erase(idsInRowOrder.begin()+rowIdx);
         idToRowIndex.erase(id);
               
         regenerate_reverse_index_starting_at(rowIdx);
      }        
      else 
      {
         printf("Error, ID %u is not in the table!\n", id);
      }
   }        

   // clear the list
   void clear()
   {           
      idsInRowOrder.clear();
      idToRowIndex.clear();
   }        
            
   // Returns the row index that (id) is at, or -1 if (id) isn't in the set
   ssize_t getRowIndexForID(uint32_t id) const
   {           
      auto search = idToRowIndex.find(id);
      if (search == idToRowIndex.end()) return -1;
      return search->second;
   }

   // Returns the ID at the given row, or -1 if (rowIdx) isn't a valid row index
   int32_t getIDAtRow(size_t rowIdx) const
   {        
      return (rowIdx < idsInRowOrder.size()) ? idsInRowOrder[rowIdx] : -1;
   }        
         
   void print() const
   {
      for (size_t row=0; row<idsInRowOrder.size(); row++)
      {
         const uint32_t id = idsInRowOrder[row];
         const ssize_t checkRowIndex = getRowIndexForID(id);
         const int32_t checkRowID    = getIDAtRow(checkRowIndex);

         printf("row=%zu id=%u checkRowIndex=%zi checkRowID=%i", row, id, checkRowIndex, checkRowID);
         if (checkRowIndex != row) printf(" ERROR:(checkRowIndex doesn't match row)");
         if (checkRowID    != id)  printf(" ERROR:(checkRowID doesn't match id)");
         printf("\n");
      }
   }

private:
   // Here's where it gets inefficient -- if I have to insert or remove IDs near the front
   // of the list I end up regenerating the reverse index a lot and if the list is long, it gets slow
   void regenerate_reverse_index_starting_at(size_t startIdx)
   {
      printf("Regenerating reverse index from row %zu to row %zu\n", startIdx, idsInRowOrder.size());
      for (size_t i=startIdx; i<idsInRowOrder.size(); i++) idToRowIndex[idsInRowOrder[i]] = i;
   }

   std::vector<uint32_t> idsInRowOrder;
   std::unordered_map<uint32_t, size_t> idToRowIndex;  // reverse-lookup
};

int main(int, char **)
{
   std::vector<uint32_t> someIDs;
   {
      while(someIDs.size()<50) someIDs.push_back(someIDs.size());

      std::random_device rd;  // Seed generator
      std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Mersenne Twister engine

      std::shuffle(someIDs.begin(), someIDs.end(), gen);  // put them in some random order
   }

   IDToRowMap map;
   for (auto a : someIDs) map.appendID(a);

   printf("Enter one of the following:\n");
   printf("   a 12345 - append ID 12345\n");
   printf("   i 12345 - insert ID 12345 at row #3\n");
   printf("   r 12345 - remove ID 12345\n");
   printf("   c       - clear the table\n");
   printf("   p       - print the table\n");
   printf("\n");

   while(1)
   {
      char buf[128];
      if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))
      {
         switch(buf[0])
         {
            case 'a':
            {
               const uint32_t id = atol(&buf[2]);
               printf("Appending id %u\n", id);
               map.appendID(id);
            }
            break;

            case 'i':
            {
               const uint32_t id = atol(&buf[2]);
               printf("Inserting id %u at row #3\n", id);
               map.insertIDAtRow(id, 3);
            }
            break;

            case 'r':
            {
               const uint32_t id = atol(&buf[2]);
               printf("Removing id %u\n", id);
               map.removeID(id);
            }
            break;

            case 'c':
               map.clear();
               printf("Cleared!\n");
            break;

            case 'p':
               map.print();
            break;

            default:
               printf("Unknown command [%s]\n", buf);
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   return 0;
}

EDIT:  A LinkedHashSet-type class (which I do have a C++ version of, and which I find very useful in other contexts) does not address this problem, because looking up the nth item of a linked list is an O(N) operation and therefore inefficient when used with a large data set.

Sidenote: why are you using all of the C-style I/O? And if you do want to do this, include <cstdio> vs. <stdio.h>. Same with <cstdint> vs. <stdint.h>

Because I dislike C++'s iostreams API.

i think O(1) is pretty far-fetched, i think the best you can get is O(log(n)) using some tree and you can play with the packing to get the base of the log high enough for no one to notice the difference.

You might want to try and find a 3rd party unordered_map.  The one provided by the standard is required to maintain certain conditions so that it is implemented as a linked list.  There are other hash maps that don't have the issues unordered_map has.

I almost feel like your program needs to use a relational database of some form.

@Chris that would be one solution, but presumably the authors of the relational database had to solve this problem at some point, so knowing how they solved it would be more educational than just dropping someone else's black box into my code.

On the subject of I/O: in main you have an infinite loop. There is no clear indication of how this is expected to end. The switch is only evaluated if fgets succeeds. Otherwise the loop is repeated. But if fgets has failed, why are you expecting it to succeed on the next loop iteration?

I don't think there is a solution that is going to be O(1) unless maybe there is some structure to the IDs that can be exploited. If they are random, I am pretty sure an O(1) mapping is impossible. You may want to do some research on "perfect hash functions". If you can generate a perfect hash function for your IDs (generally depends on key distribution/patterns), this may be possible.

The only way I could see that you could achieve O(1) position lookups is if your data structure stored both the unique ID and, for that ID, the corresponding position information.   That would mean accepting some substantial trade-offs, including  memory to store the positional information,  time to update the position information whenever inserting new elements to the map, etc.  If those sorts of trade-offs are unacceptable, the best is probably something like O(n log n) using some tree structure.   There is no free lunch.

@Peter can you describe more about how the tree structure would work?  Eg what would the keys in the tree be, and how would the tree lookups find the current row of a specified ID?

I think you're looking for something like Java's LinkedHashSet, which simultaneously maintains both an unordered lookup ("hash") and an insertion-order lookup (linked). I'm not recommending Java, though. I'm mentioning this because I found Is there a linked hash set in C++? (with an answer covering the suggestion I would make, namely Boost.MultiIndex), and I thought a little explanation might be warranted to explain why it is the same question.

@Jamit I do have something like LinkedHashSet, but it doesn't solve this problem, since you can't access the nth item of a linked list except in O(N) time, which is too slow.

You might want to take a look at the Skip list. In particular the indexed skip list. It's O(log n) lookup and update.

You're not going to get O(1) no matter what, but this sounds like a case for binary search - as long as you stick to std::vector. If you also wanted insert/erase to be fast, I'll add (implicit) treap to the list of suggestions. Constant factor of lookup will be worse but all operations are O(log n) average.
Btw with insert, do you mean insert at sorted position (and delete at any)? Can't really insert at any position without breaking sortedness.

@Xellos doesn't binary search rely on the data being in sorted order?  In this case the IDs are in an arbitrary/user-specified order, so you can't eg just look at a given ID and know where next to look in your binary search.

@JeremyFriesner Oh, I understood ordered set to mean the data is... ordered. In case of arbitrary insert/delete and lookup by key, an implicit treap (or another self-balancing BST structure that constructs exactly one node for every inserted key) combined with an internal mapping from keys to its nodes is definitely the way to go. Key lookup is summing up sizes of left-subtrees of all nodes on the path from key's node to root in the BST.
